# Are there any 'themes' for iOS developers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiappearance

I am aware that the iOS framework has a concept of `UIAppearance` which allows you to easily adjust the visual appearance of the controls in your application. What I am wondering is whether there are any published libraries of colour palettes / themes that work well in the iOS context?

For example, an iOS equivalent of jQuery Mobile theme roller:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

(NOTE: I have googled this first!)

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for a better way to style your application's interface, you have a few options.

There's the Open Source project NUI, located at https://github.com/tombenner/nui.git

It allow you to set styling using a CSS like interface. One drawback is that you have to rename some of your classes to inherent from NUI interface classes instead of standard user interface classes.

Also, there's Pixate, which allows you to directly style using CSS at http://www.pixate.com

However, it's not available yet, and it will cost $300, according to their Kickstarter page.

Comment: And now there is http://nativecss.com/ too. I haven't tested it, just added it for completeness. I'm currently using NUI, but having issues with the transition to iOS 7. Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Then there is https://github.com/robertwijas/UISS, which I also didn't try yet.

Comment: Oh, and Pixate is now free (you can still buy commercial support)

Answer (score 4):

So far I've found two options for this:

First is [App Design Vault](http://www.appdesignvault.com/). Their price range is from $59 to $89 per theme. Basically you have to use the Apply method of each theme for different elements. The drawback is that you can not modify themes and if you decide to change the theme you have to find each call to the theme apply method and change that to the new theme. However, this also gives you the ability to mix different themes and use them at the same time.

Next is [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/) which basically picks up the design from a CSS file and applies it to your elements. This has a free trial version and the licenses start from $79 which is academic and goes up to $1299. Although many CSS keywords are same as the standard CSS however you need to know their special queries and keywords to use the most out of it. Of course they are all well documented. The good thing about this is that if you decide to change the theme all you need to do is to replace a CSS file.

Both work in Objective-C and MonoTouch (Xamarin). I am now trying to see which one is a better choice for using with Monotouch.Dialog

Comment: I thought pixate was free, at least that's what their site says.

Comment: I see it as free as well, but it is referred as pixate-freestyle

Answer (score 4):

To summarize and for future reference,

App designs

- http://www.pixeden.com/mobile-apps
- http://www.appdesignvault.com/

we also have the following "CSS engines"

- http://www.pixate.com/
- https://github.com/tombenner/nui
- http://nativecss.com/
- https://github.com/robertwijas/UISS

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui) and it is available as a cocoapod and easy to use and customize. My vote for NUI, though the [Native CSS](http://nativecss.com/) is a good option if one chooses to go the commercial route. It has some very good built-in out-of-the-box styles that it comes with.

Additional to styling basic iOS Components, you can add custom styles to a particular element and make it work almost like CSS